# Tkinter Frame changes its width and height

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

For instance, I have 2 frames and both are set to 300x300.
On one of them, I put a widget in, and in the other one I don't.
The one that I put a widget on just squeezed its size to the widget's size while the first frame kept its frame since its empty.

Can I get around this and have a fixed width and height for the frame no matter what I put?

An example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x1000")
frame1 = Frame(root, bg = "blue", width = 300, height = 300)
frame1.pack()

frame2 = Frame(root, bg = "red", width = 300, height = 300)
label = Label(frame2, text = "hey").pack()
frame2.pack()
```

Comment: This is the default behavior - widgets shrink to fit their contents. You can defeat it, but it's almost never the right thing to do. Add widgets in their preferred size and tkinter will do a great job making the frame the best size it can be.

Comment: Also the variable `label` is always `None`. For more info read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66385069/11106801)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this answer: [tkinter's .pack_propagate() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996599/tkinters-pack-propagate-method)

What you're looking for is `pack_propagate`

Comment: In case you were wondering where to put it, add `frame2.pack_propagate(False)` on the line after `frame2 = Frame ...`

Comment: Thanks, I also found out that if using grid inside the frame then it should be grid_propagate(False)