# Change NavigationToolbar size of matplotlib in Tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

Is there a way to change the size of NavigationToolbar (e.g. the size of `zoom` button) when embedding matplotlib into Tkinter? I have tried to set the keywords `width` and `height` in `config`, but it did not work. So, any suggestion?

```
Update
```

```
import matplotlib
import os
import Tkinter as tk

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import NavigationToolbar2TkAgg as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import ToolTip

class CustomedToolbar(NavigationToolbar):
    def __init__(self, canvas, root):
        NavigationToolbar.__init__(self,canvas,root)

def _Button(self, text, file, command, extension='.ppm'):
    img_file = os.path.join(matplotlib.rcParams['datapath'], 'images', file + extension)
    im = tk.PhotoImage(master=self, file=img_file)
    im = im.zoom(3, 3)
    im = im.subsample(4, 4)
    # Do stuff with im here
    b = tk.Button(master=self, text=text, padx=2, pady=2, image=im, command=command)
    b._ntimage = im
    b.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    return b

def _init_toolbar(self):
    xmin, xmax = self.canvas.figure.bbox.intervalx
    height, width = 50, xmax-xmin
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master=self.window,
                                            width=int(width), height=int(height),
                                            borderwidth=2)

    self.update()  # Make axes menu

    for text, tooltip_text, image_file, callback in self.toolitems:
        if text is None:
            # spacer, unhandled in Tk
            pass
        else:
            button = self._Button(text=text, file=image_file, command=getattr(self, callback))
            if tooltip_text is not None:
                ToolTip.createToolTip(button, tooltip_text)

    self.message = tk.StringVar(master=self)
    self._message_label = tk.Label(master=self, textvariable=self.message)
    self._message_label.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
    self.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
```

This is my effort. Thanks fhdrsdg.

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or an image of the problem you are experiencing together with a clear statement of what you would want to achieve? The way your question is now makes it (at least for me) difficult to understand what your problem exactly is.

Comment: @fhdrsdg Thanks for your reply and reminding. The question is refined.

Comment: @fhdrsdg I'm sorry I can not add more comments after your answer, so I have to add my comment here. +1 for your anwser as it works. But sadly, only integers are accepted by `im.subsample` or `im.zoom`. And PIL is not standardard library in python. So if I do not use any third-party packages, I found your solution is the only way I can choose.

Comment: You could try combinations like `im = im.zoom(2, 2)` `im = im.subsample(3, 3)` to get the images at 2/3 of the size. But that doesn't really improve image quality.

Comment: Great idea! May be I have to use another images instead of matplotlib image or process the images using other powerful image processing software. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, you can create a custom toolbar class, which inherits from `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg`. You can the alter the `_Button`  definition in which the buttons are created:

```
class CustomToolbar(NavigationToolbar2TkAgg):
    def _Button(self, text, file, command, extension='.ppm'):
        img_file = os.path.join(matplotlib.rcParams['datapath'], 'images', file + extension)
        im = Tk.PhotoImage(master=self, file=img_file)
        # Do stuff with im here
        b = Tk.Button(
            master=self, text=text, padx=2, pady=2, image=im, command=command)
        b._ntimage = im
        b.pack(side=Tk.LEFT)
        return b
```

As you can see, here we have an image file im, which is the image you want to make smaller. `Tk.PhotoImage` only has `subsample()` to do this, which lets you shrink the images by a whole factor. For example you could do `im = im.subsample(2, 2)` to make the images twice as small (or `im = im.zoom(2, 2)` to make them twice as big).

Maybe someone who is more proficient with PIL could tell you if there's a way to use PIL to make the images any size you want, but I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to do and I'll try. One more question is why set keywords `width` and `height` of the attribute `config` does not work?

Comment: What object did you call `config` on?

Comment: `toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, root)`. The `toolbar` has attribute `config`.

Comment: I think `config` configures the frame in which the buttons are, so changing the size of this frame does nothing about the size of the buttons. For me, `width` and `height` do nothing at all, which I suspect has something to do with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563827/how-do-you-set-a-tkinter-frame-size).