# Why is my widget being overlapped?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am using Bryan Oakley's code at [Tkinter adding line number to text widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369470/tkinter-adding-line-number-to-text-widget) to create a `Text` widget with line numbers. But I want create a custom widget that I can use like `Text` widget but then with optional line numbers. Like in:

```
t = LinedText(top)
t.insert("insert", "Hello")
t.show()
```

But as of now, when I show line numbers, it covers text widget. The window is resized automatically. Why is that happening? My code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class TextLineNumbers(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.textwidget = None

    def attach(self, text_widget):
        self.textwidget = text_widget

    def redraw(self, *args):
        '''redraw line numbers'''
        self.delete("all")

        i = self.textwidget.index("@0,0")
        while True :
            dline= self.textwidget.dlineinfo(i)
            if dline is None: break
            y = dline[1]
            linenum = str(i).split(".")[0]
            self.create_text(2,y,anchor="nw", text=linenum)
            i = self.textwidget.index("%s+1line" % i)


class CustomText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.tk.eval('''
            proc widget_proxy {widget widget_command args} {

                # call the real tk widget command with the real args
                set result [uplevel [linsert $args 0 $widget_command]]

                # generate the event for certain types of commands
                if {([lindex $args 0] in {insert replace delete}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 2] == {mark set insert}) || 
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {xview moveto}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {xview scroll}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {yview moveto}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {yview scroll})} {

                    event generate  $widget <<Change>> -when tail
                }

                # return the result from the real widget command
                return $result
            }
            ''')
        self.tk.eval('''
            rename {widget} _{widget}
            interp alias {{}} ::{widget} {{}} widget_proxy {widget} _{widget}
        '''.format(widget=str(self)))


class LinedText(CustomText):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        CustomText.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.settings = self.Settings()
        self.linenumbers = None

        self.text = super()      

        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=self.yview)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.text.tag_configure("bigfont", font=("Helvetica", "24", "bold"))
        self.text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.text.bind("<<Change>>", self._on_change)
        self.text.bind("<Configure>", self._on_change)
        self.text.insert("end", "one\ntwo\nthree\n")
        self.text.insert("end", "four\n",("bigfont",))
        self.text.insert("end", "five\n")
        self.text.pack(side="left")

    def hide(self,event=None):
        if not self.settings.hide_linenumbers:
            self.settings.hide_linenumbers = True
            self.linenumbers.pack_forget()

    def show(self,event=None):
        if self.linenumbers == None:
            self.linenumbers = TextLineNumbers(self, width=30)
            self.linenumbers.attach(self.text)
            self.linenumbers.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        elif self.settings.hide_linenumbers:
            self.settings.hide_linenumbers = False
            self.linenumbers.pack(side="left", fill="y")

    def _on_change(self, event):
        if self.linenumbers:
            self.linenumbers.redraw()

    class Settings():
        def __init__(self):
            self.hide_linenumbers = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    text = LinedText(root)
    #text.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Hide", command=text.hide)
    button.pack()
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Show", command=text.show)
    button.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Also, I was assuming with `.pack()` as opposed to `.pack(side="left")`, widget was to be drawn below previous widgets. My buttons are being drawn to right. How do I get them to draw below text and line widgets? Do I absolutely need to use `.grid()` or `Frame`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I am not sure I understood the logic in the functions `show` and `hide`, but in the code below, as you will see, I have changed a little bit those functions.

I am also not sure why you are using `super()` to initialise `self.text` in your `LinedText` class, but I think the problem starts exactly there.

What I first did was basically to make `LinedText` inherit from a `Frame` instead of from a `CustomText`, and create an instance variable called `self.text` of type `CustomText` in your `LinedText` class. I did this because I think of this `LinedText` class as a container for 2 other objects of type `CustomText` and `TextLineNumbers`.

I also decided to split the main window (the `root`) in 2 frames, one for the `LinedText` object, and one to contain the buttons `Show` and `Hide`. In this way, I can pack the frames, instead of single widgets, and I can for example pack the frame for the buttons at the bottom, and the frame for the `LinedText` object at the top.

Using `Frames` to organise the data is often the right and easier way to go when creating layouts.

One thing I also changed to make the `TextLineNumber` look pretty is where the numbers are drawn. Check the comments on the code.

Another thing I want to say is that you should compare the value of object with `None` using `is` or `is not`, instead of `==` and `!=`.

Also, I am not seeing the point of having a class (`Settings`) just with an instance variable, it does not make sense, and I guess you are doing this because this class will become larger in the future.

If you have problems regarding the fact that the window shrinks when you introduce or remove a widget, check out this question

> [How to stop Tkinter Frame from shrinking to fit its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563827/how-to-stop-tkinter-frame-from-shrinking-to-fit-its-contents)

I hope you understand the logic of the methods `show` and `hide`, if not, just ask.

Here's the full code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class TextLineNumbers(tk.Canvas):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.textwidget = None

    def attach(self, text_widget):
        self.textwidget = text_widget

    def redraw(self, *args):
        '''redraw line numbers'''
        self.delete("all")

        i = self.textwidget.index("@0,0")

        while True :
            dline= self.textwidget.dlineinfo(i)
            if dline is None: break
            y = dline[1]
            linenum = str(i).split(".")[0]

            # changed where text is draw: it starts from 4
            self.create_text(4, y, anchor="nw", text=linenum)  
            i = self.textwidget.index("%s+1line" % i)


class CustomText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.tk.eval('''
            proc widget_proxy {widget widget_command args} {

                # call the real tk widget command with the real args
                set result [uplevel [linsert $args 0 $widget_command]]

                # generate the event for certain types of commands
                if {([lindex $args 0] in {insert replace delete}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 2] == {mark set insert}) || 
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {xview moveto}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {xview scroll}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {yview moveto}) ||
                    ([lrange $args 0 1] == {yview scroll})} {

                    event generate  $widget <<Change>> -when tail
                }

                # return the result from the real widget command
                return $result
            }
            ''')
        self.tk.eval('''
            rename {widget} _{widget}
            interp alias {{}} ::{widget} {{}} widget_proxy {widget} _{widget}
        '''.format(widget=str(self)))


class LinedText(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.settings = self.Settings()
        self.linenumbers = None

        self.text = CustomText(self)
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=self.text.yview)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.text.tag_configure("bigfont", font=("Helvetica", "24", "bold"))
        self.text.bind("<<Change>>", self._on_change)
        self.text.bind("<Configure>", self._on_change)
        self.text.insert("end", "one\ntwo\nthree\n")
        self.text.insert("end", "four\n",("bigfont",))
        self.text.insert("end", "five\n")
        self.text.focus()        
        self.text.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)

    def hide(self,event=None):
        if not self.settings.hide_linenumbers:
            self.settings.hide_linenumbers = True
            self.linenumbers.pack_forget()
            self.linenumbers = None

    def show(self,event=None):
        if self.linenumbers is None:
            self.linenumbers = TextLineNumbers(self, width=30)
            self.linenumbers.attach(self.text)
            self.linenumbers.pack(side="left", fill="y")
            self.settings.hide_linenumbers = False

    def _on_change(self, event):
        if self.linenumbers:
            self.linenumbers.redraw()

    class Settings():
        def __init__(self):
            self.hide_linenumbers = True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()

    top_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    text = LinedText(top_frame)
    text.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
    top_frame.pack(side="top", expand=1, fill="both")

    bottom_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    button = tk.Button(bottom_frame, text="Hide", command=text.hide)
    button.pack(side="right")
    button = tk.Button(bottom_frame, text="Show", command=text.show)
    button.pack(side="right")
    bottom_frame.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I inherit from `Text` because I want to call `Text` methods directly from my `LinedText`. Now I have to do `self.text.insert()`. If I inherit from `Text` I can do `self.insert()`. Maybe I can place the frame as property/attribute/`self.frame` instead. I am using `super` to get instance of `CustomText` so that I can pack it.

Comment: @SureshSubedi To be honest, I had never seen the use of `super` like in your example. Usually, you just use `self.` to refer to the current instance... Anyway I understand typing less can be easier, but in this case I think the way I structure the class is better, but you decide.

Answer (score 2):

The reason they overlap is that you make the line number widget a child of the text widget. You need to use a frame that is the parent of both the text widget and the line number widget, and then pack or grid them side-by-side. This is exactly how the original code you copied from works.

Comment: I am trying to create something like `ScrolledText`. It also uses `Frame` to place `Scrollbar` and `Text` in it but it inherits from `Text` and has `Frame` as attribute. When I did that linenumbers didn't get updated. Must have something to do with two hacks involved in ScrolledText and CustomText breaking eachother. But maybe I'll have to make a new question for that.