# Python Tkinter Label in Frame

Tags: python, tkinter, label, frame

I want to place a label inside a frame in tkinter, but I can't figure out how to actually get it inside.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

W=tkinter.Tk()
W.geometry("800x850+0+0")
W.configure(background="lightblue")

FRAME=Frame(W, width=100, height =50).place(x=700,y=0)

LABEL=Label(FRAME, text="test").pack()
```

When I run this, it doesn't place the Label inside the frame, but just places it normally on the window.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the line

```
FRAME=Frame(W, width=100, height =50).place(x=700,y=0)
```

You think you are returning a tk frame, but you are not! You get the return value of the place method, which is `None`

So try

```
frame = Frame(W, width=100, height=50)
frame.place(x=700, y=0)
label = Label(frame, text="test").pack()
```

If you don't want the frame to shrink to fit the label, use ([How to stop Tkinter Frame from shrinking to fit its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563827/how-to-stop-tkinter-frame-from-shrinking-to-fit-its-contents))

```
frame.pack_propagate(False)
```

Note: Either `import tkinter` or `from tkinter import *` but not both. Also, by convention, names of instances of objects are lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you're assigning `FRAME` to `Frame(W, width=100, height =50).place(x=700,y=0)`, as opposed to just the actual frame, and according to the [Place Manager reference](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm), there doesn't seem to be a return value. Try this:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

W=tkinter.Tk()
W.geometry("800x850+0+0")
W.configure(background="lightblue")

FRAME=Frame(W, width=100, height =50)
FRAME.place(x=700,y=0)

LABEL=Label(FRAME, text="test").pack()

W.mainloop()
```