# Placing tkinter Label inside Frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying to place the label a,b inside frame 2.

```
import random
from  tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title("Rock Paper Scissor")

root.geometry("600x600")

# user choice frame
frame1 = Frame(root, height=200, bg="cyan")
frame1.pack(fill=X)
# frame1.pack_propagate(0) # stop frame from force fit

Button(frame1, text="ROCK").pack(side=TOP)
Button(frame1, text="PAPER").pack(side=TOP)
Button(frame1, text="SCISSOR").pack(side=TOP)

# score frame
frame2 = Frame(root, height=50,bg="orange").pack(fill=X)
a = Label(frame2, text="Your score")
b = Label(frame2, text="Computer score")
a.pack()
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

but whenever i run this code label a and b show below the frame 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39580739/python-tkinter-label-in-frame)

`Frame(root, height=50,bg="orange").pack(fill=X)` does not return a frame, instead it returns `None`. So your `frame2` is always `None`.

You should do the same as you did for the `frame1`.

```
frame2 = Frame(root, height=50, bg="orange")
frame2.pack(fill=X)
```

Comment: So it was all caused by having .pack() in same line. damn i will remember this.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
import random
from  tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title("Rock Paper Scissor")

root.geometry("600x600")

# user choice frame
frame1 = Frame(root, height=200, bg="cyan")
frame1.pack(fill=X)
# frame1.pack_propagate(0) # stop frame from force fit

Button(frame1, text="ROCK").pack(side=TOP)
Button(frame1, text="PAPER").pack(side=TOP)
Button(frame1, text="SCISSOR").pack(side=TOP)

# score frame
frame2 = Frame(root, height=50,bg="orange")
frame2.pack(fill=X)
a = Label(frame2, text="Your score")
b = Label(frame2, text="Computer score")
a.pack()
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```