# How to place the button in a given frame in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Here, I need to place the button in homeFrame. But I can't place the button there. What's the issue? Please resolve it. Here is the code.

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
root.configure(bg='#498240')

screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

headFrame = Frame(root,width=screen_width,height=120,bd=10,bg='#498240',relief=RIDGE).grid(row=0,column=0)
headlable = Label(headFrame,text='Super Market',fg='white',bg='#498240',font=('times new roman',55,'bold')).grid(row=0,column=0)

homeFrame = Frame(root,width=screen_width,height=screen_height-200,bd=10,bg='#498240',relief=RIDGE).grid(row=1,column=0)
homeBtn = Button(homeFrame,text='Customer Management').grid(row=0,column=0)


root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Here I have mentioned the location of the button please help me to place the button there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63536505/how-do-i-organize-my-tkinter-appllication/63536506#63536506

Comment: @Atlas435 I have searched all over but can't resolve can you please resolve this issue please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've fallen in to the standard trap of creating a widget and using grid on the same row.

Split them up like this

```
homeFrame = Frame(root,width=screen_width,height=screen_height-200,bd=10,bg='#498240',relief=RIDGE)
homeFrame.grid(row=1,column=0)
homeBtn = Button(homeFrame,text='Customer Management')
homeBtn.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

If you do

```
homeFrame = Frame(root).grid()
```

homeFrame will contain "None" and any widget that you try to place in "None" will have root as its parent. But if you do

```
homeFrame = Frame(root)
```

homeFrame will contain a valid instance of a tkinter frame in which widgets can be placed.

Lesson is that you should never create a widget on the same row as you use grid/pack/place (unless you don't ever refer to that widget again)

PS, a tkinter frame will automatically re-size to fit any child widgets, you can force it to not do this by following the guidance at this question [How to stop Tkinter Frame from shrinking to fit its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563827/how-to-stop-tkinter-frame-from-shrinking-to-fit-its-contents)

Comment: Would you mind about explainig the issue. So the OP is able to understand what he did wrong?

Comment: @Atlas435 Explained.

Comment: also headFrame.

Comment: @stark Left as an incomplete solution for Xor96 to solve.